# if $x = 0$ then $y \ne b$

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, constraint, binary-variable

I'm trying to model the following:

if $x=0$ then $y \ne b$

$y$ is a positive  integer number( $y\le U$) and $x$ is binary and $b$ is a constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introduce binary variables $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
z_1+z_2 +z_3&= 1 \tag1\\
1z_1+bz_2+(b+1)z_3 \le y &\le (b-1)z_1+bz_2+Uz_3 \tag2\\
z_2&\le x\tag3
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ enforce the three disjoint cases $y<b$, $y=b$, and $y>b$. Constraint $(3)$ enforces $x=0\implies z_2=0$, and $z_2=0$ excludes the $y=b$ case.